# What is the microsoft recommended page assets organization for site?

Tags: asp.net-webpages, project-organization

I've found that when making a new site I get a structure like this:

```
Content\
   themes\
      base\
         images\
         jquery.ui.all.css
         ...
      Site.css
Controllers\
Models\
Scripts\
   jquery.js
   ...
```

I'd prefer to keeps all page assets in a single directory (moving Scripts into Content), but I feel like this isn't the recommended structure, but I haven't found any reference to this layout explicitly -- granted I have not devoted too much time to it.

What does MS recommend for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft do not make any recommendations in terms of static content folder structures. They make templates that follow a similar structure to each other but that's more convention than a recommendation. I doubt they would ever recommend one folder structure over another as it makes no difference whatsoever.

Comment: I agree it makes little (to no difference) except that NuGet packages with content deployed into a project expect an organization -- it seems that they got a layout in mind.

Comment: But the layout that they work to is not a recommendation. I wouldn't even use the word "expect". If a Scripts folder doesn't exist when you download jQuery, Nuget creates one. And even then, that convention is determined by the package author, not Microsoft.